# how to differentiate between common parts of the triangle and extract linestring from it

Tags: python, postgis-1.5, shapely

Can you help me break down shape A to different linestrings: lines *2 & 3* AND line *1*?  The shape contains three different polygons (A, B, C). I wish to determine the start/end point of each part with the common points of the other polygons.

I'm using Postgis 1.5 / Python Shapely

[image: A1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection of A and B's exterior rings will be your segment 3, yes?

```
line3 = a.exterior.intersection(b.exterior)
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks! it did.
line3 = a.boundary.intersection(b.boundary)